# Redirect URL with C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a blog that currently uses Joomla. But as I need to make some settings becoming a mini blog with a mini system, I'm porting the Joomla MVC 4 for a C # application.

My problem is that the old URLs are in default:

```
http://www.sesmt.com.br/portal/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1494:dds1494&catid=60:art-dds&Itemid=78
```

How do I get the id and send this URL for a URL type "http :/ / site.com / Blog / Article / id"

And when the idea is MVC 4 application, receive http://www.sesmt.com.br/portal/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1494:dds1494&catid=60:art-dds&Itemid=78 he goes to http: // site.com/Blog/Article/id. the id is the original URL.

Comment: Your question is unclear. We can provide an MVC route for what you want.. but how you tie that into your integration attempt is not possible to answer without a whole lot more detail.

Comment: Post edited from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to create MVC Routes if you want to shape the url.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BlogRoute",
                url: "Blog/Index/{view}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                    {
                        controller = "Blog",
                        action = "Index",
                        view = "Article",
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional
                    }
                );
```

What you are saying about MVC 4 recieving your PHP URL doesn't make any sense to me.  If you want to do some automagic redirection that has to be done in IIS.